# Trying to create multiple views with forEach results in "Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'Content' conform to 'MapContent'"

Tags: swiftui, foreach

A search for this exact error has turned up nothing on the entire Web. I just want to create a number of copies of a view, abutted end to end, to create a horizontal layout akin to a ruler. At runtime it will create enough segments to cover a particular length.

I get the above error, however. Adding `id:\.self` to the `forEach` **doesn't fix the problem**.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MediaPositionView: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
        HStack(spacing: 0)
        {
            ForEach(0..<10)
            { index in
                songSegment(segIndex: index)    // Static method 'buildExpression' requires that 'Content' conform to 'MapContent'
            }
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder func songSegment(segIndex: Int) -> any View
    {
        ZStack
        {
            Color.blue
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            Path
            { path in
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 5, y: 25))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 5, y: 50))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `songSegment` should return `some View` not `any View`.

Comment: Thanks! The compiler said this: "Use of protocol 'View' as a type must be written 'any View'" Pretty misleading. "some View" did indeed solve it. I'm happy to mark this as an answer if you'd like to post it.

Comment: best make a View and use body as the view builder cause it does another few tricks